# Why is the data not being show correctly when fetching information from a site?

Tags: javascript, weather, openweathermap

I am currently coding a weather application (for fun) that gets the users longitude and latitude (with permission) and then will display the current weather. Unfortunately the weather data is not being logged in the console correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```
const api = "API---";


window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
            let lat = position.coords.latitude;
            let lon = position.coords.latitude;
            let data = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&appid=${api}`;
            console.log(lat, lon, data);
            fetch(data)
                .then((r) => {
                    return r.JSON;
                })
                .then((data) => {
                    console.log(data);
                })
        });
    };
});
```

Instead of the weather being logged, this is being logged

```
ƒ json() { [native code] }
```

I am using open weather, but the API key will not be publicly shown.  Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:
`return r.JSON`

According to the [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json), the `.json()` function is, well, *a function*. You need parentheses to call it, just like any other function.  If you change that line to `return r.json();`, it should work.  I tested on my side with my API key (albeit without the `navigator.geolocation` stuff you had), and this worked for me.

As for why you're seeing `ƒ json() { [native code] }`, that's because you've returned an actual function.  So, when you `console.log` that returned value, it's displaying a *function*, not the data you want.

In other words, your issue here seems to be a typo, forgetting to include parentheses on your function call.  Including parentheses should fix your issue.

Comment: @Jake if this helped you, you can upvote and accept it as the answer.  If you're still having issues, I'd be happy to try and help some more.

Answer (score 0):

The output is this because you are returning r.JSON which is a function thus data in second then is

```
ƒ json() { [native code] }
```

it should be

```
fetch(data)
    .then((r) => {
        return r.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

json is the correct function that parses JSON response into native JavaScript objects and returns a promise that resolves with JavaScript Object corresponding to the response